# Should you be able to close as duplicate from another SE site?

Tags: feature-request, exact-duplicates, vote-to-close

see the following link on SU

[MS Outlook 2010 - Force Automatic Replies to all Email Senders](https://superuser.com/questions/539668/ms-outlook-2010-force-automatic-replies-to-all-email-senders)

I can see the question and answer exist approptiately in both SU and SF sites.  It could be an MS Exchange related question and answer (server) and Outlook related question and answer (client).

Should there be an ability to close something as an exact duplicate on another SE site?
Or should it be able to exist on both sites?

Comment: Relevant: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4708/what-to-do-with-cross-site-duplicates/4713#4713 (but apparently not duplicate)

Comment: Also related is http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/1458. The Christianity.SE meta discussion expands more on how exactly it is and is not appropriate to cross-post.

Answer (score 4):

If it exists on both sites it should be worded to fit the different audiences. If they're not, one should be surrendered, migrated and merged with the other.

If you do find the answer exists better or bests on another site in the network, just quote it, link back with attribution and maybe even frame it, again, for the audience you're answering among.

So the posts should either be tailored for the audience or moved to the more fitting one.